# make child to come out of overflowing parent

Tags: css, reactjs, z-index

I am using a Modal component, from our in house component library. The Modal component has a Header, Body and a Footer section.

The Modal Body has **overflow: auto and max-height set**. When the the content we are providing to the Modal Body is longer, then overflow comes into effect and Modal body becomes scrollable. I want to retain the Modal body this way, with added functionalities for the custom type ahead as discussed below.

[image]

I am adding a custom type ahead component towards the end of the MODAL BODY. When I start typing, the type ahead list expands the parent div and does not pop out of the MODAL. It has high z-index and it goes over all its siblings. I need to style the type ahead list such that it always pops out.

This is what is expectation :

[image]

This is what is happening :

[image]

I have been trying hard and it has not been possible so far without setting height and overflow:hidden/visible to the Modal Body. Any ideas would be welcome.

I have created a small piece of code to replicate the issue.
[Code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-custom-dropdown-example-forked-fnb2j?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: Does changing `overflow: auto` to `overflow: visible` solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you. Actually, the modal has lot more contents and I want the box to have overflow:auto. If I change to 'visible', I am loosing my ability to scroll.

Comment: The thing with overflow is, you can't have overflow-x: scroll, overflow-y: visible/auto. That is just how [overflow attribute](https://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html) works unfortunately.  I suffered a lot from that too. If you want both functionalities, you have to change it with `onClick` events is my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

change .container to overflow visible
add background-color: black to select-box--items

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-custom-dropdown-example-forked-6h95w?file=/src/styles.css check the modified code here

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the modal has lot more contents and I want the box to have overflow:auto. If I change to 'visible', I am loosing my ability to scroll.